# Populating column with if condition not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the following DataFrame:

```
    0             1               2
1  10/1/2016    'stringvalue'     456
2  NaN          'anothersting'    NaN
3  NaN          'and another '    NaN
4  11/1/2016    'more strings'    943
5  NaN          'stringstring'    NaN
```

I want to create a new column 'Full Entry' that is based on a condition. 
If the value of df[2] is NaN df['Full Entry'] should be NaN as well.

If df[2]  != NaN df['Full Entry'] should take the value of df[1]. 
I want to repeat this for each row.

I've come up with the following code

```
df['Full_Entry'] = [df[1] if pd.isnull(x) == False else np.NaN for x in df[2]]
```

But this gives me the following results

```
    0             1               2     Full_Entry:
1  10/1/2016    'stringvalue'     456     0 stringv... 
2  NaN          'anothersting'    NaN     NaN
3  NaN          'and another '    NaN     NaN
4  11/1/2016    'more strings'    943     0 stringv...
5  NaN          'stringstring'    NaN     NaN
```

Yet what I want is this:

```
    0             1               2     Full_Entry:
1  10/1/2016    'stringvalue'     456     stringvalue 
2  NaN          'anothersting'    NaN     NaN
3  NaN          'and another '    NaN     NaN
4  11/1/2016    'more strings'    943     more strings
5  NaN          'stringstring'    NaN     NaN
```

The 'if' condition in my code seems to trigger at the right moments, but only uses the value of the first row. And for some reason a '0' is included as well.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `df['Full_Entry']=np.where(pd.isnull(df.2), np.NaN, df.1)`

Comment: That solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

`df['Full_Entry']=np.where(pd.isnull(df.2), np.NaN, df.1)`

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
`pd.Series.mask`

```
df['Full Entry'] = df.iloc[:, 1].mask(df.iloc[:, 2].isnull())
```

Or,

```
df['Full Entry'] = df.iloc[:, 2].mask(pd.notnull, df.iloc[:, 1])
```

```
df

           0             1      2    Full Entry
1  10/1/2016   stringvalue  456.0   stringvalue
2        NaN  anothersting    NaN           NaN
3        NaN   and another    NaN           NaN
4  11/1/2016  more strings  943.0  more strings
5        NaN  stringstring    NaN           NaN
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.Series.where` -

```
df['Full Entry'] = df.iloc[:, 2].where(pd.isnull, df.iloc[:, 1])    
df

           0             1      2    Full Entry
1  10/1/2016   stringvalue  456.0   stringvalue
2        NaN  anothersting    NaN           NaN
3        NaN   and another    NaN           NaN
4  11/1/2016  more strings  943.0  more strings
5        NaN  stringstring    NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

One can also use `apply` function:

```
df['Full Entry'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.NaN if pd.isnull(x[2]) else x[1], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           0             1      2    Full Entry
1  10/1/2016   stringvalue  456.0   stringvalue
2        NaN  anothersting    NaN           NaN
3        NaN   and another    NaN           NaN
4  11/1/2016  more strings  943.0  more strings
5        NaN  stringstring    NaN           NaN
```