# Not able to read text data into a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read text data from [Pandas : populate column with if condition not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034373/pandas-populate-column-with-if-condition-not-working-as-expected) into a dataframe. My code is:

```
dftxt = """
    0             1               2
1  10/1/2016    'stringvalue'     456
2  NaN          'anothersting'    NaN
3  NaN          'and another '    NaN
4  11/1/2016    'more strings'    943
5  NaN          'stringstring'    NaN
"""

from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dftxt), sep='\s+')
print (df)
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mydf.py", line 16, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dftxt), sep='\s+')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1508, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:10415)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:10691)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 924, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:11437)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 911, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:11308)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 2024, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:27037)
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 5, saw 6
```

I can't understand which 6 fields are being read in error: `Expected 4 fields in line 5, saw 6` . Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 5 would be this one -

```
 3  NaN          'and another '    NaN
 1   2             3    4     5     6
```

The problem lies with your separator. It's interpreting each space separated word as a separate column. In this case, you'd need to

- change your `sep` argument to `\s{2,}`, and
- change your engine to `'python'` to suppress warnings

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dftxt), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

Also, I'd get rid of the quotes (they're superfluous) using `str.strip` -

```
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].str.strip("'")
df

           0             1      2
1  10/1/2016   stringvalue  456.0
2        NaN  anothersting    NaN
3        NaN  and another     NaN
4  11/1/2016  more strings  943.0
5        NaN  stringstring    NaN
```

---

Lastly, from one pandas user to another, there's a little convenience function called [`pd.read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) I think you should take a look at. It reads data from clipboard and accepts just about every argument that `read_csv` does.

Comment: It works very well. Why is `engine='python'` needed? Code seems to work well without this option also.

Comment: @rnso Correct. By default, the 'python' engine is used for variable width separators, because the C engine doesn't seem to support it. It still throws a warning though. Explicit is better than implicit! (remember the Zen of Python.)